# In R, how to pass arguments from an outer function to an inner function?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

In R, I'm trying to pass arguments from an outer function to an inner function, where they will be evaluated. This fails, presumably because the arguments are not evaluated when they are passed.

Here are two examples; one uses match.call() to grab the arguments of the outer function and pass them along, the other manually binds the arguments of the outer function in a list, then calls the inner function. I suspect that I'm failing to grasp some of the intricacies of match.call() and lazy evaluation. Is there an elegant way to fix this problem?

```
# Use match.call to pass arguments to inner_function
outer_fun_a <- function(formula, data){
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  mods <- names(get_all_vars(formula, data = data))[-1]
  inner_function(mods, args)
}
# Make a list of the arguments of outer_fun_b
outer_fun_b <- function(formula, data){
  args <- list(formula = formula, data = data)
  mods <- names(get_all_vars(formula, data = data))[-1]
  inner_function(mods, args)
}

inner_function <- function(modvars, args){
  args$formula <- update(args$formula, paste0("~ ", paste(modvars, collapse = " + ")))
  do.call(lm, args)
}

df <- iris
# This fails, because the arguments in args have not been evuated
outer_fun_a(as.formula(paste0("Sepal.Length ~ ", paste(names(df)[2:5], collapse = " + "))),
            df)
# This succeeds
outer_fun_b(as.formula(paste0("Sepal.Length ~ ", paste(names(df)[2:5], collapse = " + "))),
            df)
```

Comment: would `force` solve your problem?

Comment: At the moment, I don't see how exactly. Can you please illustrate where/how you would use it?